# Position a child form relative to the position of a control located on the main form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a main form and a number of CheckBoxes on it.
When I click one of the CheckBoxes, I display a child form containing the information related to the clicked CheckBox.
The problem is that the child form pops up very far from the clicked CheckBox, even though I set the StartPosition of the child form to Manual and I set the form Location to (CheckBox.Location.X + 20, CheckBox.Location.Y)

Answer (score 0):

The CheckBox.Location is relative to the form you're on. The top left corner point of the client area of your form is 0,0 and all the controls on it are positioned relative to that point.

You need some way of converting the controls relative position to screen position and that is provided by [PointToScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_PointToScreen_System_Drawing_Point_).

Assuming that your sub-form is called frmSubForm you'd use the following:

```
frmSubForm.Location = this.PointToScreen(new Point(CheckBox.Location.X + 20, CheckBox.Location.Y));
```